# Null pointer Exception - FindViewById() when calling ListView

Tags: java, android

I am trying to make a bluetooth scanner app but im having problems. The app automatically closes when start. It gives me the error:

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.widget.ListView.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference
at com.example.bluetoothscanner.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:40)

Line 40 is where I call the listview from the layout and i dont know how to fix it.

MainActivity.java:

```
package com.example.bluetoothscanner;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;

import android.Manifest;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    // Declaración de clases
    public static final int REQUEST_ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION = 1;
    public static final int REQUEST_ENABLE_BLUETOOTH = 11;
    private ListView devicesList;
    private Button scanningBtn;
    private BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> listAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Get bluetooth adapter
        *devicesList.findViewById(R.id.bluetoothList);*
        scanningBtn.findViewById(R.id.button);
        bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

        // Se crea un ArrayAdapter para mostrar los resultados en una lista
        listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
        devicesList.setAdapter(listAdapter);

        //Miramos el estado del bluetooth
        checkBluetoothState();


        scanningBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(bluetoothAdapter != null && bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled())
                {
                    if(checkCoarseLocationPermission())
                    {
                        listAdapter.clear();
                        bluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery();
                    }
                }else
                {
                    checkBluetoothState();
                }
            }
        });

        // Se comprueba permisos al empezar la app
        checkCoarseLocationPermission();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        registerReceiver(devicesFoundReceiver,new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND));
        registerReceiver(devicesFoundReceiver,new IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_STARTED));
        registerReceiver(devicesFoundReceiver,new IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED));

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        unregisterReceiver(devicesFoundReceiver);
    }

    // Funciones para comprobar los permisos
    private boolean checkCoarseLocationPermission(){
        if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,new String[] {Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION},REQUEST_ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION);
            return false;
        }else{
            return true;
        }
    }
    private void checkBluetoothState(){
        if (bluetoothAdapter == null){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Bluetooth is not available in this device",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else{
            if (bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()){
                if(bluetoothAdapter.isDiscovering()){
                    Toast.makeText(this,"Scanning for bluewtooth devices",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(this,"Bluetooth is enabled",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    scanningBtn.setEnabled(true);
                }
            }
            else{
                Toast.makeText(this,"You need to enable bluetooth",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent enableIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
                startActivityForResult(enableIntent,REQUEST_ENABLE_BLUETOOTH);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(requestCode == REQUEST_ENABLE_BLUETOOTH){
            checkBluetoothState();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

        switch(requestCode) {
            case REQUEST_ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION:
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Access coarse location enabled, you can scan Bluetooth devices", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Access coare location forbidden, you can not scan Bluetooth devices", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    // Se implementa el recividor para poder detectar otros dispositivos
    private final BroadcastReceiver devicesFoundReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();

            if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
                BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                listAdapter.add(device.getName() + "\n" +device.getAddress());
            } else if(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED.equals(action)){
                scanningBtn.setText("Scanning Bluetooth Devices");
            } else if(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_STARTED.equals(action)){
                scanningBtn.setText("Scanning in progress...");
            }
        }
    };
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:text="@string/BtnText"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.837" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/bluetoothList"
        android:layout_width="272dp"
        android:layout_height="453dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="52dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.496"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason why the error happened is because there is no such function call findViewById in the devicesList object. In order to pass the listView into devicesList, you must pass it like this.

```
devicesList = findViewById(R.id.bluetoothList);
```

Comment: You are so right, thank you very much!

Comment: For what it's worth, there is such a method (`View#findViewById()`) but you cannot invoke methods on null objects.

Answer (score -1):

findViewById id used as

```
devicesList = findViewById(R.id.bluetoothList);
```

not as

```
devicesList.findViewById(R.id.bluetoothList);
```

Comment: YOU ARE SO DAMN RIGHT, IVE BEEN STUCK ON THIS FOR AN HOUR NOW. THANK YOU VERY MUCH. 
believe it or not, is not my first app, had a mental break down though

Comment: then tick me up!!

Comment: already did, sais it doesnt show because of my reputation but its recorded!

Comment: @Harsh0021, you could write your answer without "Omg, Actually you are a beginner!", it does not add any value to your answer.